# Bloquear um botão dentro de uma dataTable no primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Tenho o seguinte problema, possuo uma `dataTable` que contem a possibilidade de editar os dados utlizando a edição pela linha, usando a tag `rowEditor` e `cellEditor`. Junto deste possuo um botão para deletar aquela linha. Quando eu clico no botão editar gostaria de bloquear o botão excluir, para não permitir o usuário que durante a edição utilize este botão e outros, mas o foco principal é o botão excluir.

Tentei utilizar os eventos da `dataTable` com `ajax` mas não esta sendo possível. Alguém me indica alguma saída para tal problema?

Esta `datatable` esta dentro de um `form` com `id="form"` e um `panelgroup` que engloba outra `datatable` que pretendo implementar a mesma funcionalidade.

Como posso realizar tal fato e se posso...

```
<p:dataTable id="tabelaVigenciaCorrente" editable="true"
    value="#{tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaCorrente.faixas}"
    emptyMessage="Adicione pelo menos uma faixa" var="corrente"
    sortBy="prazoMinimo">

    <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{tabelaTaxaBean.setBotaoDesativado(true)}" update="btnExcluirFaixaCorrente"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update=":form:messages"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tabelaTaxaBean.setBotaoDesativado(false)}" update="btnExcluirFaixaCorrente"/>

    <f:facet name="header">
        <div align="left">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{tabelaTaxaBean.cabecalhoVigenciaCorrente}" />
        </div>
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Prazo (em meses)">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel
                    value="#{corrente.prazoMinimo} a #{corrente.prazoMaximo}" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Prazo inicial"
                    value="#{corrente.prazoMinimo}" size="8" maxlength="3"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this, soNumeros)" required="true" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <p:inputText label="Prazo final" value="#{corrente.prazoMaximo}"
                    size="8" maxlength="3" onkeypress="mascara(this, soNumeros)"
                    required="true" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Taxa de juros">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{corrente.taxaJuros}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:outputLabel value="%" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Taxa de juros" value="#{corrente.taxaJuros}"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this,valorMonetario)" size="11"
                    maxlength="6" required="true">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Taxa diferenciada para o banco/empresa">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{corrente.taxaDiferenciadaParaBanco}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:outputLabel
                    value="#{corrente.taxaDiferenciadaParaBanco == null ? '' : '%'}" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Taxa diferenciada para o banco/empresa"
                    value="#{corrente.taxaDiferenciadaParaBanco}"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this,valorMonetario)" size="11"
                    maxlength="6">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Comissão">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{corrente.comissao}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:outputLabel>

                <p:outputLabel value="%" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Comissão" value="#{corrente.comissao}"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this,valorMonetario)" size="11"
                    maxlength="6" required="true">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Complemento">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{corrente.complementoComissao}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:outputLabel>

                <p:outputLabel
                    value="#{corrente.complementoComissao == null ? '' : '%'}" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Complemento"
                    value="#{corrente.complementoComissao}"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this,valorMonetario)" size="11"
                    maxlength="6">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Ação" style="width: 7%"
        styleClass="coluna-acao">
        <p:rowEditor />
        &nbsp;
        <p:commandButton id="btnExcluirFaixaCorrente" process="@this" styleClass="botaoImagem"
            icon="botaoExcluir" title="Excluir" disabled="#{tabelaTaxaBean.botaoDesativado}"
            oncomplete="confirmationFaixaExclusao.show()">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                target="#{tabelaTaxaBean.vigenciaTipo}" value="corrente" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{tabelaTaxaBean.faixa}"
                value="#{corrente}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <div align="right">
            <p:commandButton
                disabled="#{tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaCorrente == null}"
                process="@this" value="Adicionar faixa"
                update=":dialogAdicionarFaixa" oncomplete="dlgFaixa.show();"
                action="#{tabelaTaxaBean.criarFaixa}" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                    target="#{tabelaTaxaBean.vigenciaTipo}" value="corrente" />
            </p:commandButton>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <p:commandButton process="@this" update=":dialogVigencia"
                oncomplete="dlgVigencia.show()" value="Editar vigência"
                action="#{tabelaTaxaBean.editarVigencia}"
                disabled="#{(tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaCorrente == null) || (tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaProxima != null)}" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                    target="#{tabelaTaxaBean.vigenciaTipo}" value="corrente" />
            </p:commandButton>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <p:commandButton process="@this" update=":dialogVigencia"
                oncomplete="confirmationVigenciaExclusao.show()"
                value="Excluir vigência"
                disabled="#{(tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaCorrente == null) || (tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaProxima != null)}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                    target="#{tabelaTaxaBean.vigenciaTipo}" value="corrente" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </div>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a *Client Side API* do componente commandButton através do atributo `widgetVar` para desabilitar seus botões utilizando apenas javaScript. 
No seu commandButton

```
<p:commandButton ... widgetVar="botao1" />
```

e na tag ajax:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" oncomplete="botao1.disable()" />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" oncomplete="botao1.enable()" />
```

caso deseje realizar alguma ação no server side os listeners desses eventos recebem a classe `org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent` como parametro.

Comment: Cara houve um usuário que sugeriu o mesmo, mas não sei porque, quando eu clico na linha 1 ele não bloqueia, mas se eu clicar na linha 2 funciona normal. E outro problema que eu vi, caso eu edite um valor mas um dos campos for requerido, a validação do `JSF` barra para salvar, mas ai o botão de deletar é desbloqueado.

Comment: @Macario1983 Era minha resposta, mas a excluí porque você disse que já resolveu somente com jQuery ia postar a sua solução, lembra?

Comment: @filipeportes Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! É um prazer tê-lo por aqui participando da comunidade. Abraço.

Comment: Pois é cara, eu gostaria de pedir desculpa porque o meu código funciona quase igual sua sugestão, mas deu esse problema acima citado, kkkkk, mas o problema é o seguinte como citei acima, se acontecer uma validação nos campos ao editar, e não passar, o botão é desbloqueado.

Comment: Obrigado pelas boas vindas!!

Comment: @filipeportes você irá tentar mostrar outra solução?

Comment: estou um pouco corrido pra montar um ambiente e testar, mas sugiro continuar tentando com a idéia de um listner que altera um boolean, e este fica atrelado ao disable do commandButton.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, consegui!

Segue as funções em `js` or `jQuery`.

```
  function disableBtnExcluir() {
      $('button[id*="tabelaVigenciaCorrente"]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
  }

  function enableBtnExcluir() {
      $('button[id*="tabelaVigenciaCorrente"]').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
  }
```

Como chamar na página

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" onstart="disableBtnExcluir();" />
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" oncomplete="if (args.validationFailed) disableBtnExcluir(); else enableBtnExcluir();" />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" oncomplete="enableBtnExcluir();"/>
```